# ASP.NET 5: What is the difference between the "dnx451" and the "aspent50" frameworks?

Tags: asp.net-core

In Visual Studio 2015, I've created a new ASP.NET MVC 5 Web API project. When I looked at the project.json that was created I saw this bit of configuration:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },
```

Since I needed to use EF6 and following advice in [the answer to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33040733/asp-net-5-web-project-and-entity-framework-in-separate-projects), I've removed the reference to "dnxcore50".

However, [the answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886638/why-does-adding-a-dependency-in-my-web-api-asp-net-v5-project-not-work-fully) mentions an altogether different framework: "aspnet50".

What is the difference between "dnx451" and "aspent50"?

Comment: Do you really want to use MVC5 and EF6 and not MVC6 and EF7 from ASP.NET 5 RC1-update1? dnxcore50 is open source version of DotNet see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/) which will be intensively developed now and which exist for multiple operation systems. It would be good if your application can be compiled for both frameworks. Isn't so?

Comment: @Oleg Tx. The benefit of running my project on non-Windows OSs is smaller, for me, than the cost of using bleeding edge technologies. EF7 (and MVC6) are far from release and have far fewer helpful resources online at this time. As they mature, I will most likely migrate.

Comment: `dnxcore50` is important not only for other operation systems. It's just another implementation of DotNet (many parts are the same of cause) which will be intensively developed now. It contains factored API which can provide better performance and less memory requirements, but it don't have some features like AppDomains (which you probably not use). Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34331499/315935) where I described some reason about the usage of both frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

The new ASP.NET 5 is very new and still very changing. Even the naming changed.

There was [an announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/3) that changed the name `aspnet50` and `aspnetcore50` to `dnx451`/`dnx452`/`dnxcore50` back in April.

Then [at the end of October](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/98), `dnxcore50` became `dotnet5.4` and `dnx451` became `net451`.

So yeah... those should be the final rename and we shouldn't see any new *monikers* as they are called.

#### About removing `dnxcore50`

When you need to do that, it's basically because a library that you are using might not support `dnxcore50` yet so compilation fails. `dnxcore` (or `dotnet5.4`) will works cross-platform while `net451` will only work on Windows.